# Unable to change round robin time quantum in real time linux

Tags: c++, real-time, scheduling

I'm writing a C++ program on SUSE Linux Real Time and is trying to gather timing statistics on its round robin(RR) scheduling policy. I am able to set the policy to RR via

```
#include <sched.h>
...
struct sched_param sparms;
sparms.sched_priority = 99;
if (sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, &sparms) < 0){
   perror("sched_setsched");
   exit(1);
}
```

and is able to determine the time quantum via `sched_rr_get_interval()`. The OS documentation stated that the time quantum can be changed via a process's nice value. However, doing so had no effect. I changed the nice value via `nice()` and confirmed that it is indeed changed via `getpriority()`, yet `sched_rr_get_interval()` returns the same time.
Anybody knows what's going on?

Edit: Added code below. `setpriority()` did not work.

```
...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
...
// Set scheduler to RR
struct sched_param sparms;
sparms.sched_priority = 99;
if(sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, &sparms) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting thread scheduling policy & priority.");
    exit(-1);
}
timespec qtm;
sched_rr_get_interval(0, &qtm);
fprintf(stderr, "Time quantum(thread 1): %lds %ldns.\n", qtm.tv_sec, qtm.tv_nsec);
fprintf(stderr, "Current nice value: %d\n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0));
if(nice(90) < 0) fprintf(stderr, "Error setting time quantum.\n");
//setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 10);
fprintf(stderr, "New nice value: %d\n", getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0));
sched_rr_get_interval(0, &qtm);
fprintf(stderr, "New time quantum(thread 1): %lds %ldns.\n", qtm.tv_sec, qtm.tv_nsec);
...
```

Edit: OS version: 2.6.33.7-rt29-0.5-rt

Comment: @wmjdgla: What is your kernel version? Could you post the code that calls `nice` and `sched_rr_get_interval`?

Comment: Can do, but have to wait till tomorrow (it's 10:44pm right now) since the code is sitting in a computer in the lab, and I'm back home already. Will have to go back to check the version too. Thanks for looking!

Comment: It might also be worth trying what @Jason suggested in a now-deleted comment: call `setpriority()` instead of `nice()`.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered cookie based accounts. Please consider registering by associating an OpenID with your account so that you don't lose the ability to manage your questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks! Tried to register by clicking "click here to sign up" but the page just proceeded to display 3 scrolling dots. It's still the same after 3 minutes.

Comment: @Mike `setpriority()` didn't work. I've updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the ability to control the round-robin time quantum has been removed from the Linux real-time scheduler.

Looking at the source (`kernel/sched_rt.c`), the timeslice counter is restored to a constant value (`DEF_TIMESLICE`, defined as 0.1s) when it expires in `task_tick_rt()`, so there is no way to change it dynamically. `get_rr_interval()` (called by `sched_rr_get_interval()`) always returns that constant value

If you need smaller timeslices, I guess you'll have to do it yourself with the FIFO scheduler and calls to `sched_yield()` at suitable times, or hack the kernel to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux kernel version 3.9 and later, the RR quantum can be read and changed using /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms

If you are using a kernel version 2.6.24 or later, you cannot used the "nice" hack.